# Add Cordova Diagnostic Plugin in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, cordova-plugins

I'm new in ionic and I want to use Corodova Diagnostic plugin in my ionic project. I don't know how to use plugins in ionic. I've added this plugin using this command.

```
 $ cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

I can see this plugin in my list using

```
 $ cordova plugins ls
```

now i have a seperate controller file, i am post its code here, when i try to use this , it give error, cordova is

```
 angular.module('timetools_controllers', ['ui.utils', 'ionic','cordovaGeolocationModule'])

.controller('TimetoolsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$localstorage', '$ionicPopup', function ($scope, $http, $localstorage, $ionicPopup) {

    /*=================================================================================*/
    // ABFRAGE OB TRACK & SHARE AKTIV IST
    /*=================================================================================*/
    var fdappAuth = $localstorage.getObject('fdappAuth');

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://app.flugdeck.com/options.php?apikey=7ksmewzSUd2asSA0384cosb!2w3SloE&do=get&optid=110&userId=' + fdappAuth.fdappUserId + '&userPwHash=' + fdappAuth.fdappUserPw,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
        .success(function (data, status) {
            // Verarbeitet die Daten und setzt diese zur Anzeige in die scopes
            console.log("Optionsabfrage für Track & Share läuft");

            $scope.optentry = data[0];
            $scope.optentry.opt_110 = data[0].opt_110;

            if ($scope.optentry.opt_110 == 1) {
                $scope.isTrackShareActive = "Tracking ";
                $scope.cssClass = "Tracking";
            } else {
                $scope.isTrackShareActive = "Tracking ";
                $scope.cssClass = "Tracking";
            }
        });


    $scope.saveOffBlockTime = function () {
        var datum = new Date();
        console.log("Datums-String: " + datum);

        // Erstelle das Datum und Poste das
        if ($scope.OffBlockRunAlready === true) {

        } else {
            // Setzt das Datum
            $scope.OffBlockTime = datum;


            $scope.OffBlockRunAlready = true;

            if ($scope.optentry.opt_110 == 1) {
                /***********************/
                // GPS TEST CODE CORDOVA
                /***********************/
                alert("GPS TEST");
                 cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
                    console.log("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
                }, function(error){
                    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
                });



            }

        }
    }; // saveOffBlockTime








}]) ;// Ende .controller('TimetoolsCtrl'...
```

but it give following error in console.

```
 ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

Can anybody help me please?

my Index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<!-- build:css dist_css/styles.css -->
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<!-- build:js dist_js/modules.js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-md5/angular-md5.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-cordova-geolocation/cordovaGeolocationModule.js">      </script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- build:js dist_js/app.js -->
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/directives.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/templates.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/services.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/config.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/mymodules.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ui-utils.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller_flightlog.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller_timetools.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller_infotools.js"></script>
<script src="dist/dist_js/app/factories.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-app="your_app_name">
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please also add your index.html file? On which environment are you testing? (browser, emulator, phone)

Comment: i am testing on browser, and i have posted my index.html @mhx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Github page](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) for this plugin states:

> This Cordova/Phonegap plugin for iOS and Android is used to check the state of the following device settings

The plugin is specifically intended to report the status of native device settings on **Android** and **iOS** platforms.

Hence, it does not support the **browser** platform and running it on this will result in the observed error.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to take in mind when testing ngCordova plugins in your browser via `$ ionic serve` is that it often result in **cordova is not defined**.

Most ngCordova plugins will not work in a web browser because they use native device code.

Can you please try to emulate your app en check if it works? (You might want to change that console.log() to something else so you can see if it works in your emulator. Print a $scope for example.)

Example: `$ ionic emulate ios` or `$ ionic emulate android`.